# Algorithm for 3D Bin Packing Problem on pallet

Tags: 3d, bin, packing, bin-packing

I am looking for algorithm for 3D Bin Packing Problem. My task is:

I have a conveyor on which I am receiving boxes of 4 sizes (300x200x160, 400x300x220, 600x400x340, 700x510x340). These boxes have to be packed on a pallet (1200x800x1800) with the best possible way. I don't know in advance which specific type of box I will receive and how many of them, I just have to take the box and put it on pallet in the best possible way, so that I can put there as many boxes as possible.

I was looking for any type of algorithm, but could not find anything good.

thanks for any idea :)

Answer (score 0):

i hope my english will be understandable :)

Funny, i have the same story, so i started to simulate it and i could do it for 2 differents size of boxes, im working now on a better version of it for maybe more boxes, i dont know if it will help you but here's how i did it :

1: even if you have a lots of differents boxes size you only have  few spot on the pallet that can accept those " big " boxes, so you'll need to give priority on those boxes, specialy if you can't like put them on side for later

2: you  dont know what boxes will come, but you have a dimension that wont change, your pallet, X and Y so you'll need to calculate the Maximum X and Y that the pallet can receive

an exemple of what i try to explain :

I've 2 boxes A and B , and B is twice the dimension of A
and the pallet maximum is 3 A and 1 B. in this case it's easy when 3 A come , you can put them side by side, then let's say the big one come well B will take the last place on the pallet.

but now let's say i have first B then 3 A , i wont put B where i placed A is the exemple above, because if i do so i would only be able to place 1B and 2A
so i prioritise the most efficenty spot and allways put B on a specific position. and in this case if A come i know i have the place for it.

sorry, hard for me to give you explanation, but i can send you a video and some code if you want.

Comment: Adding a formatted code example is the best thing you can do for this answer.

Comment: Hi, yes, If you can, send me your code or video on my email - timco.vanco@gmail.com ! Thanks a lot! :)